# Testable method for calling global javascript functions in angularjs controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scorm2004

## Very Global Description

You have functions that must exist in the global scope. You want a way to encapsulate the functionality of these functions in a dependency injectable way so they are more testable. What is the correct way to do this?

## Somewhat Specific Description

I have a situation where I have an existing javascript library that uses a lot of variables and function in the global scope. The library is a SCORM engine and part of the standard dictates that the functions must be available in the global scope (so user created content can access them).

However, there are a couple of places in various controllers that I must call them as well. At the moment I an just calling them, but this makes testing those lines difficult and seems to violate the angular mindset in general.

### Plnkr

[A plunk just illustrating how things are
   now](http://plnkr.co/edit/InKmSn?p=preview)

```
var globalVariable = 1;

function globalFunction(){
  return "cats";
}

var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', [ '$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.cats = globalFunction(); //This line is hard to test and makes me feel dirty.
}]);
```

[A plunk that wraps the function in a factory (maybe what is recommended in comments?)](http://plnkr.co/edit/qlmsV5?p=preview)

```
var globalVariable = 1;

function globalFunction(){
  return "cats";
}

var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.factory('angularFriendly', function(){
  this.globalFunction = globalFunction;
  return this;
});

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'angularFriendly',
  function($scope, angularFriendly) {
    $scope.name = 'World';
    $scope.cats = angularFriendly.globalFunction();
  }
]);
```

This is more or less what I mean in my original comment when I said I considered wrapping it in a service. I make the function injectable (which is good and is much more testable) but I am not sure it is good practice (because I have just moved the difficult to test code to a different place).

Comment: I had though of wrapping the parts of the existing code in a service. This would allow me to inject it various places in the angular app. However, it seems that this is sort of just moving the bad practice to a service instead of a controller .

Comment: you can reach globals from any function, hence their name, but readup on https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di if you want to avoid the closure and specific name binding

Comment: @dandavis I know I can reach globals from any function (it is what I am doing now). I also know about dependency injection. My concern isn't really the name binding (as a matter of fact because of the standard I can't get around that it has to happen). What I am hoping for is way to encapsulate the global functions in a way I can inject them (so that controllers will be more testable). I will edits the question to better indicate this.

Comment: well, i meant you could define your own DI with the global, and then test against the local...

Comment: @dandavis Could you perhaps make a small example of this with a fiddle or plunk and post it as an answer? If it works I will happily accept it. As it stands I am a bit confused about what you mean.

Comment: i don't know angular, but you can modify the example on the link, around myModule.factory('greeter', function($window){, replacing "alert" with your global and "greeter" with something you want to call it as when you use a formal parameter of _greeter_ in a controller function. make sure to call the injector, but that's about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer wrapping 3rd party non-Angular applications into value objects (which is functionally the same as using a factory and immediately calling it prior to injection, which feels cleaner).

```
var globalVariable = 1;

function globalFunction(){
  return "cats";
}

var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
app.value('external', globalFunction);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'external',
  function($scope, external) {
    $scope.name = 'World';
    $scope.cats = external();  // Treat the dependency as a service to resolve into the scope
  }
]);
```

Comment: This seems similar to the service approach (though a tad more light weight overall. I hadn't considered using a value instead of the service. It still feels like a kludge to me but that is probably just the nature of using non-angular code in angular. Thanks!